# finding whether a exe is called or not from windows service in windows 7

Tags: asp.net

i created a windows service from which i call cmd.exe
But i dont know whether it is called or not 
please suggest some answer

```
    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(@"c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe");
            info.UseShellExecute = false;
            info.RedirectStandardError = true;
            info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            info.CreateNoWindow = true;
            info.ErrorDialog = false;
            info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

            Process process = Process.Start(info);
```

Comment: wont it be shown in Task manager?

Comment: no,it is not showing there.

Comment: does `cmd.exe` open? is your service running?

Comment: my service is running but cmd.exe is not present .Is my code correct

Comment: You need to add code which sends you email when particular step is going on or 'before start' or 'after end'.

Answer (score 0):

Windows services are inside svchost.exe

Comment: my service is running, but i want to see whether cmd.exe is called or not.How i find it?Is my code okay or need to change